# ERROR:tornado.general:WebSocket ... Swampdragon : DoesNotExist: matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, docker, tornado, swampdragon

I followed the first tutorial at : http://swampdragon.net/tutorial/part-1-here-be-dragons-and-thats-a-good-thing/

I work with Docker. I had to open ports 9999 and 6379 and run like this :

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti -p 8000:8000 -p 6379:6379 -p 9999:9999 --name swarmdragon --net host -v /DJANGO_PATH/:/swarmdragon swarmdragon-install bash
```

(can't acces to localhost:9999 from host without "-net host" option. Don't know why :/ )

When the docker container start, I have to start these process :

```
service redis-server start
./manage.py runsd
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And everything seems to work in the host machine but :

- I have to refresh when i add the first "TodoList object" to see it, but all the new "TodoItem object" appear well when i add, without refresh (that's the point ^^)
- I don't see another "TodoList object" if I add it in the admin panel. Even if I refresh.
- I get a strange error in the console from "./manage.py runsd" when I delete all the "TodoList object" and refresh the page. Same when i add a new "TodoList object" when I create a new one after the delete :

:

```
-------- SwampDragon ------
Running SwampDragon on 127.0.0.1:9999
DRAGON_URL: http://localhost:9999/
Version 0.4.2.2
Debug: True
Quit the server with ctrl+c
---------------------------
ERROR:tornado.general:WebSocket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sockjs/tornado/transports/websocket.py", line 60, in on_message
    self.session.on_messages(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sockjs/tornado/session.py", line 418, in on_messages
    self.conn.on_message(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swampdragon/connections/sockjs_connection.py", line 90, in on_message
    raise e
DoesNotExist: TodoList matching query does not exist.
```

Django version : 1.8.6

Python : 2.7

Swampdragon just installed with pip

Did you know where this comes and how to correct ?

Many Thanks.